# Autolayout constraint where height is the sum of sub view heights

Tags: cocoa, autolayout

Is it possible to create an autolayout constraint where the height of a view is the sum of its sun view heights?

I have a design where a view contains sub view 1 and sub view 2 vertically stacked. 
Sub view 1 is a fixed height, but sub view 2 should be able to alternate between zero height and its content height.

Autolayout is killing me for this.

Comment: This may be wrong thinking. It might be a result of thinking in frames and rects and needing to learn to think in terms of relative constraints.

Comment: Are you creating your constraints in a nib/storyboard or in code?

Comment: I want them in code to have more flexibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create a constraint pinning the top of sub view 1 to the top of it's superview, as well as a constraint pinning the bottom of sub view 2 to the bottom of it's superview. The constraint format string would look like this:

```
@"V:|[subview1][subview2]|"
```

This would also create the constraint that subview1 and suvbview2 are touching, which is probably what you want.

Comment: Ok ignoring that this doesn't set a fixed height for subview1, this scenario, how would you resize subview2 ?

Comment: You can add those constraints in another line. If you make a constraint @"V:[subview2(500)]" you can save a pointer to that constraint and later adjust the size by setting the constant (from 500 to whatever your new height should be). The layout engine is really efficient at adjusting constants of existing constraints.